# Can I set Properties.Settings.Default.VariableName = Some_value in Mono under linux?

Tags: linux, mono

I want to know if i can get/set application properties in Mono under Linux, like the way i can under visual studio 2010?

For example, to set a value to a var in application settings, can i do this?

```
Properties.Settings.Default.VariableName = Some_value
```

Thanks,
Anjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those properties are code that Visual Studio generates for you behind the scenes (See \Properties\Settings.Designer.cs).  If you let VS build the code for you and use it, it will run on Mono on Linux.  However, Mono does not have any support for generating the code that I am aware of.

Comment: Thanks :) i will have to find another way to store data in mono